# No value provided for placeholder expressions

Tags: flyway

Despite setting flyway.placeholderReplacement=false I keep seeing error about no value provided for placeholder expression in sql by Flyway

> ERROR: Unexpected error
>       org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions:  & conditions.  Check your configuration!
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.oracle.pro.SQLPlusPlaceholderReplacer.replacePlaceholders(SQLPlusPlaceholderReplacer.java:132)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.line.PlaceholderReplacingLine.getLine(PlaceholderReplacingLine.java:36)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.extractStatements(ExecutableSqlScript.java:156)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.ExecutableSqlScript.(ExecutableSqlScript.java:133)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.oracle.OracleSqlScript.(OracleSqlScript.java:61)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.oracle.OracleDatabase.doCreateSqlScript(OracleDatabase.java:126)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.Database.createSqlScript(Database.java:163)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.getSqlScript(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:96)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.executeInTransaction(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:109)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.isExecuteGroupInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:312)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigrations(DbMigrate.java:275)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:244)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$100(DbMigrate.java:53)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:163)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.call(DbMigrate.java:160)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.Connection$1.call(Connection.java:145)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.Connection.lock(Connection.java:141)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.lock(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:150)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrateAll(DbMigrate.java:160)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:138)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:947)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:910)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1238)
>         at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:910)
>         at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:161)
>         at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:108)
>       Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>       Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 4):

Using spring boot, in `application.yml`.
Add the below `placeholderReplacement: false`

```
 flyway:
    baseline-on-migrate: false
    sql-migration-prefix: V
    table: migration
    placeholderReplacement: false
```

This was happening, because i had in my .SQL migration file, HTML code with ${name}.

So it was trying to replace that! and i want it to be **as is**, to be inserted in the database.

**Summary**: in my case i want it always disabled, as i have no use of it

**References**: [Possible Usages In Different Configuration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/placeholderReplacement)

Answer (score 3):

I think, best way to resolve this error - it's override default prefix and suffix

```
flyway.placeholderPrefix=$${
flyway.placeholderSuffix=}
```

because disabling this functionality may be unacceptably for some reasons: using flyway variables, for instance.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to solve this issue with flyway CLI. 
`-placeholderPrefix=$${` 
solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

`flyway.placeholderReplacement=false` is only for Flyway placeholders, not SQL*Plus placeholders.

To disable SQL*Plus-specific placeholders, you must include `SET DEFINE OFF` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is similar to mine (you cannot disable placeholders and you cannot change the prefix), an alternative way is to break the placeholder value. Let's says you SQL is:

```
UPDATE table SET value = '${variable}';
```

You can avoid FlyWay picking up the placeholder by using something like:

```
UPDATE table SET value = '$' + '{variable}';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can encode the whole string with UTF-8, then decode it when you need to use it